# WSDL Client from Intellij generated code

Tags: java, web-services, intellij-idea, wsdl, jax-ws

I am trying to make a client connect to a web service and use a SetFlight method on the server.

The environment is Intellij Ultimate, Java 7, and JAXWS. The generation of the classes from the WSDL has been done.

Among the generated classes I have two services:

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "FOService", targetNamespace = "http://temporaryuri.org.au/", wsdlLocation = "http://fovanil.com/FOService.svc?wsdl")
    public class FOService
    extends Service
        {

        private final static URL FOSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION;
        private final static WebServiceException FOSERVICE_EXCEPTION;
        private final static QName FOSERVICE_QNAME = new QName("http://temporaryuri.org.au/", "FOService");

            static {
...
```

And the IFO service

```
@WebService(name = "IFOService", targetNamespace = "urn:fo.com.au/schema/common")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
@XmlSeeAlso({
    ObjectFactory.class
})
public interface IFOService {


    /**
     * 
     * @param parameters
     * @return
     *     returns svc.SetFlightResponse
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "SetFlight", action = "http://fo.com.au/SetFlight")
    @WebResult(name = "SetFlightResponse", targetNamespace = "urn:fo.com.au/schema/common/types", partName = "parameters")
    public SetFlightResponse SetFlight(
        @WebParam(name = "SetFlightRequest", targetNamespace = "urn:fo.com.au/schema/common/types", partName = "parameters")
        SetFlightRequest parameters);

}
```

I have looked at some examples of implementing a client https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html however this differs.

I would have thought using this would be:

```
IFOSerice service = new IFOService();
service.SetFlight(someinstanceofflight); //setFlight is not a available method
```

How do I make a client and use the SetFlight method?

Comment: How did you generate the classes from the WSDL? WHen using CXF to do this I need to tell it to generate the client implementation vs server implementation. Unfortunately I am not very familiar with Intellij in this area.

Answer (score 1):

This code worked:

```
    SetFORequest request = new SetFORequest();
    SetFOResponse response = new SetFOResponse();
    request.setFO(flight);
    FOService foService = new FOService();
    IfoService ifoService = foService.getWSHttpBindingIFOService();
    ifoService.setFO(request);
```